# How fix macOS Catalina error "not authorized to send apple events to terminal"?

Tags: security, terminal, macos-catalina, appleevents

When trying to open Maxima.app under macOS Catalina (10.15.1), I get a pop-up error message ""Not authorized to send apple events to terminal".

Where, exactly, in he Catalina System Preferences (presumably somewhere in Security & Privacy) do I allow the access?

The Automation section seems a plausible place, except that I see no way to add any app there.

Comment: Could you describe, what is Maxima.app? Is it your application from the Xcode?

Comment: Maxima is a mathematical application (a so-called "computer algebra system"). See:   http://maxima.sourceforge.net. It has a graphical front end that sends commands to Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a launcher to avoid this error. For instance:
http://webdiis.unizar.es/u/spd/WxMaximaSPD.zip
Source:

```
-- This program launches Maxima.
-- Tue Oct  1 22:08:50 CEST 2019
-- SPDsoft

do shell script "bash -c 'export M_PREFIX=/Applications/Maxima.app/Contents/Resources/opt; export PYTHONPATH=${M_PREFIX}/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/; export MANPATH=${M_PREFIX}/share/man:$MANPATH; export PATH=${M_PREFIX}/bin:$PATH; open -a ${M_PREFIX}/Applications/wxMaxima.app'"
```